# MS Teams Incoming Webhook issue

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've created an incoming Teams Webhook connector within a Teams group (using the method below).
I can successfully curl to the webhook internally and get the message to display ok.
MS have checked my tenant and access is as expected.
When I apply my URL for the webhook to any external service they eventually come back stating there was a problem detected with the webhook (Please make sure that your webhook endpoint of xxx is responding with a 2xx response code within 30 seconds of initial connection.)
Can anyone advise what else may need to be done?
Thanks

In Microsoft Teams, choose More options (⋯) next to the channel name and then choose Connectors.
Scroll through the list of Connectors to Incoming Webhook, and choose Add.
Enter a name for the webhook, upload an image to associate with data from the webhook, and choose Create.
Copy the webhook to the clipboard and save it. You'll need the webhook URL for sending information to Microsoft Teams.
Choose Done.

Comment: Hi @GDaly,

Could you please test the incoming webhook url using postman and let us know the payload result or status code. Would be help full for us to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Incoming webhooks are special type of Connector in Teams that provide a simple way for an external app to share content in team channels and are often used as tracking and notification tools. Teams provides a unique URL to which you send a JSON payload with the message that you want to POST, typically in a card format. Cards are user-interface (UI) containers that contain content and actions related to a single topic and are a way to present message data in a consistent way. Please test the incoming webhook url using postman and let us know the payload result or status code. Would be help full for us to understand more.